# Modifying text box in layout view through ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layouts, date, text-element

I have the following textbox in a layout view:

[image]

Is it possible to modify the text through ArcPy?

I made that box as text, and it has no function added to it:

[image]

I just want to change the date so that later I can export it as PDF.

Comment: Why you are not using dynamic text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change the text. Use the ListLayoutElements to find the object you want. Get the text from the element. Find and replace the text, then push the changed text back to the element. Finally refresh the view and save the mxd.

If your textbox is tagged with a name, then finding the correct layout element is easier.
I have attached an example where I am running a find and replace on an element names "iso9001" [image: textbox properties with named element]

```
def updateISO9001(find_text, replace_text):
    # create map document object instance
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    mxd.activeView = "PAGE_LAYOUT"

    # Build a dictionary of just the TEXT_ELEMENTS
    element_dict = {}
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        element_dict[elm.name] = elm


    # Is the expected tagged elemnt found
    if "iso9001" in element_dict:
        # Replace the string
        theString = element_dict["iso9001"].text
        theString = theString.replace(find_text, replace_text)
        element_dict["iso9001"].text = theString
    # Refresh the layout so the changes show
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    # remove map document object instance
    del mxd
```